# VS2003 error while performing build/rebuild solution in Release Mode

Tags: visual-studio, build, compiler-errors

I have VS2003 ASP.NET web application and when I perform build/rebuild solution in debug mode it compiles and build perfectly with no errors,

but when I change the mode to Release and try to perform a Build Solution or Rebuild solution I am getting following compile-error for various dlls that I am referencing.

I have replaced name of the name space with generic xyz

**The type or namespace name 'xyz' could not be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

All my refernces are correct and I am able to compile in debug mode without any errors.

My OS is Windows Vista

does anyone know why I am getting this error in Release mode and a possible workaround for this issue?

Following is the sample from output window

i have changed files name , i have not changed the actual errors

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: XYZ, Configuration: Release .NET ------

Preparing resources...
Updating references...
Performing main compilation...
C:\xyz\a.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToolLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\xyz\a.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToolLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\xyz\a.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToolLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\xyz\a.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToolLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\xyz\a.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToolLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\xyz\a.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToolLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\xyz\b.cs(4,7): error CS0246: error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Globals' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\xyz\c.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToolLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\xyz\d.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Logger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

..........

and so on

----------


Build complete -- 26 errors, 0 warnings
Building satellite assemblies...
Satellite assemblies could not be built because the main project output is missing.
```

Comment: Is there anything in the Output window which shows an error loading the reference?

Comment: I have added the excerpt from the output window.

Comment: Do you have a `#if` statements with the constant DEBUG or RELEASE in them. Maybe some using statements are getting disabled based on your build configuration.

Comment: Did you compare your build settings in DEBUG mode with those in RELEASE mode carefully?

Comment: @Mike ,there are no #if statements anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I closed the solution and deleted .suo file associated with solution  and opened the solution again and I was able to compile in both debug and release mode.

I have not changed anything else in the solution.

thanks all for your comments.